# What is percentile max, min, avg, current and total in Grafana/Infludb

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Just wanted to clarify what does percentile average, minimum and maximum means. To my understanding percentile is one value. e.g. 95th percentile = 2.2 sec means 95 % of total requests has response time below 2.2 sec.

So in that case in grafana dashboards I have seen when calculate percentile we can choose below figures as well

```
Average
Minimum
Maximum
Current
Total
```

This is the InfluxQL query I am using

```
SELECT mean("pct95.0") 
FROM "$measurement_name" 
WHERE ("application" =~ /^$application$/) 
  AND $timeFilter 
GROUP BY "transaction", time($__interval) fill(null)
```

This data has been pushed from Jmeter tests.

[image]